# JavaScript - mathematical operations on variables

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to make a character card for my project. Only 3 points are to be available. If you add 1 + 1 + 1, the result is 111. How do I get the result to be 3?

Here is my code
HTML

```html
        <div id="container">
            <form id="form">
                <h1 style="text-align:center;font-size:32px;">Character Card</h1>
                <br><br>
                <h3>Skill 1</h3>
                <input type="number" min="0" max="2" value="0" id="input">
                <br><br>
                <h3>Skill 2</h3>
                <input type="number" min="0" max="2" value="0" id="input2">
                <br><br>
                <h3>Skill 3</h3>
                <input type="number" min="0" max="2" value="0" id="input3">
                <br><br>
                <input type="button" onclick="Check()" value="Check value">
                <h2 id="error">You can only allocate 3 points</h2>
        </form>
        </div>
```

JavaScript

```js
function Check() {
        var skill1 = document.getElementById("input").value;
        var skill2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
        var skill3 = document.getElementById("input3").value;
        var value = skill1 + skill2 + skill3;

        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = value;
        
        if(value == 0) {
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'Choose your character points';
        }
}
```

And this is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spwuya7f/51/)

Comment: "If you add 1 + 1 + 1, the result is 111." — No, you get that if you add "1" + "1" + "1"

Comment: parseInt() is your friend.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'm newbie :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var skill1 = document.getElementById("input").value;  // = "1"
var skill1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("input").value);  // = 1
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dw3yxka9/

Comment: Thank you so much :) It works. I'm newbie in javascript.